# Why my media query is not working in real even after successful responsive tested?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

On large screens from 1920px X 1080px, header background image will be header-bg-po2.jpg, and for smaller screens than that, header background image will be header-bg-po.jpg.

To test, I gave general css for all screens:

```css
.jumbotron.job-header.po {
background: url(images/header-bg-po.jpg) no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-color: #252f36;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-size: cover;
}
```

and media query:

```css
@media (min-width: 1900px) and (min-height: 1060px) {
.jumbotron.job-header.po {
background: url(images/header-bg-po2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
}
```

It works correctly on all responsive checkers I have tested with, but not in real. When I check using large screen desktop (1920px X 1080px) in real, it shows header-bg-po.jpg, but not header-bg-po2.jpg .. Why? What is wrong here?

Even, works if I gave min-height: 979px or less than 979px. See page http://live.technosway.com/html/1023/jios-comingsoon/003/job-product-owner.html and the responsive checker http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://live.technosway.com/html/1023/jios-comingsoon/003/job-product-owner.html|1920|1080|1

If it is having such issue, then I am afraid if all other media queries for mobiles will not also work like this..? I can not check all screen sizes in real.

Please guide me..

Thanks.

Comment: Check browser support for media queries. May be you are using an older version of browser on target device.

Answer (score -1):

Have you resolved the issue? I tried it in Chrome browser and it works.

[image: tested in chrome]

Comment: hi.. thanks for checking.. but no.. the problem is not solved. As I already told, it works if you check via any responsive checker.. but it is not working in real, if you see from actual desktop which has 1920X1080 px resolution, you will see that it is not working.. 

So, as you are using google responsive checker, it seems to be working.. but in real large screens, it is not working.. :-( this is why I am confused that what is wrong..